# htaccess blocking all bots and all IPs except

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all IP address but mine (1.2.3.4)
and
I want redirect all bots but Googlebot, googlebotimage, googlebotmobile, MSNBOT, Slurp.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=^Googlebot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=^googlebotimage [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=^googlebotmobile [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=^MSNBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=^Slurp [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

My concern is, will my code be blocking the Googlebots and such?

Comment: This is specifically against Google's rules — your site will be delisted if it's not accessible by real users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `!=` operator then you cannot use regex pattern as it needs to be fixed string.

Change your rule to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(Googlebot|googlebotimage|googlebotmobile|MSNBot|Slurp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.othersite.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```